# LLNCS reference order problem

Tags: bibliographies, lncs

I have prepared a paper using `LLNCS` class and `splncs03` bibliography style. It seems the default behaviour of the style is to order references alphabetically. However, I need them to be listed based on their appearance order. Does anybody have a solution?

Comment: If the journal style is alphabetical that is what you should do. Publishers set the rules for journals, not authors.

Comment: I have had a situation where the conference overrules what the publisher wants...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Joseph Wright wrote, if alphabetic order is what Springer asks for, you should use it.

Having said that, you may get away with using an older version of their bibliography style, which you can find here: ftp://ftp.springer.de/pub/tex/latex/llncs/latex2e/splncs.bst

That one orders by appearance.